# How to change the canonical link from a category or taxonomy archive?

Tags: links, plugin-wpml

On this url: https://www.phuket-luxury-villas.us.com/tourist-spots/buddhist-temples-wats/ I have a wrong canonical link:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.phuket-luxury-villas.us.com/tourist-spots/buddhist-temples-wats/" />
```

It used to be the follow canonical link:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.luxuryvillasphuketthailand.com/tourist-spots/buddhist-temples-wats/" />
```

I tried to use this code:

`function yoast_seo_canonical_change_woocom_shop( $canonical ) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        echo '';
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'yoast_seo_canonical_change_woocom_shop', 10, 1 );`

But it seems that is put now too many canonical links on the website...

Any idea what else I can do?

This mentioned url, is an archive (done with Toolset). And we are using WPML. Sadly WPML won't let us to duplicate categories or taxonomies

Comment: It sounds like you need to determine where all the canonical tags are coming from. I'd suggest disabling Yoast temporarily, clearing cache if needed, and checking to see if a canonical is still on the page. If so, then Yoast may not be what you need to adjust. But if the canonical is gone you'll know it's Yoast. I do know that their filters usually expect a `return` rather than an `echo`, so you could try changing the command, but the filter may not accept an empty string at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself:

```
function yoast_seo_canonical_change_archives( $canonical ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'tourist-spots' ) ) {
    $path = parse_url( $canonical, PHP_URL_PATH );
    return 'https://www.luxuryvillasphuketthailand.com' . $path;
    }
    return $canonical;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'yoast_seo_canonical_change_archives', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: There's no reason Yoast's would be incorrect unless there was already something like this that was making it incorrect. Check existing code and the settings first.